# How to select an option based on value

Tags: php, html

This is my php code.

```
 $list .="<option value='$A $B'> $A,$B </option>";
```

I want to put a select option based on data. for example if $A = 1 and $B =2 then the option value get selected.

Normaly I would do it through this code

```
<?php echo $A == '1' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>
```

but since the $list is already in php quotes I cant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
$list .="<option value='$A $B' ". ($A == '1' ? 'selected : '') ."> $A,$B </option>";
```

Option 2:

```
$selected = $A == '1' ? 'selected : '';
$list .="<option value='$A $B' $selected> $A,$B </option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer doesn't actually provide the desired effect, I'll post a correct method.

```
$list.="<option value='$A $B'".($A==1 && $B==2?' selected':'')."> $A,$B </option>";
```

This is an inline conditional that checks if both `$A equals 1` and `$B equals 2`.  When both are true, the attribute is added to the option, otherwise an empty string is added to the option.

Comment: Got my vote here for the details